# Excel Export is not working in Odoo

Tags: excel, csv, export, odoo

I am currently having a problem using the default Excel Export tool from Odoo. I am using Odoo 8, but not the lastest version.

The weird thing is that for the same version of Odoo, one of my databases works fine with the Excel export tool, but the other one does not. The CSV export tool works fine in both. I installed the web_export_view module and it also works fine in both databases.

The error occurs when when I press the button to actually export the fields selected. The server it self does not do anything (just loads a little bit), but where I can see the error is in the browser's console, here is the error message:

http://localhost:8059/web/export/xls Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
POST http://localhost:8059/web/export/xls 404 (NOT FOUND)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. I tried every single thing I could think of.

Have a nice day!

Comment: pls post the error log

Comment: That's one problem...there is no error log. The only log that you can see is the one I posted above. I got it from the browser console. It is like a javascript log or something like that

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows Event Logs (Application section) ?

Comment: No, actually I haven't. Do you think that the Odoo server can throw any information there when exporting information to a Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing localhost will work you need to give full path or Temp folder path where file save for time being.

Eg:- C:\path\tem or C:\web\export\xls

Comment: I don't think that is quite the correct answer...I even created a brand new database with the same version of the Odoo server and the Excel export tool worked just fine for the new database...It does not affect whether you are using a localhost or a server in the cloud...I think that there might be something in the database that is giving problems because I don't believe is the code that is giving problems...thanks for the help anyway :)